# Finding out where is my mouse when I handle the MouseLeave event?

Tags: silverlight, timer

I am trying to get a popup to show when the mouse enter a button.

It should then hide if the user **leaves the popup**.

But for a good user experience, the popup should also **stay open if the user goes back on the button.**

So when the mouse gets out of the popup, the mouse leave event is triggered, but I don't want to handle it if the mouse entered the button at the same moment.

Is there any way of knowing if the mouse is over another control in the mouse leave event?

I have tried many different approach without success. Tell me if you have a different approach to the problem too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a timer when the `MouseLeave` event on your popup is fired, along with a boolean, perhaps called `closingPopup`, to `true`. The timer will set `closingPopup` to `false` and hide the popup. On the MouseEnter event of the button, if closingPopup is true, then stop the timer and set the boolean to false.

That or a variant of that should get you what you want. You can give it a 1/4 second delay that way. Or any amount that seems responsive.

Edit: You should probably also add the same check to `MouseLeave`for the button. (Glad I could help!)

Comment: I validate your response because that was just enough to get me going.I started implementing that earlier and for some reason tried another approach before being finished... Thanks! I started to be desperate. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by starting a timer when the mouse leaves the button, when the timer ticks, close your popup. If the mouse re-enters the button, stop the timer.

```
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyPopUp.IsOpen = false;
  timer.Stop();  
}

private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  timer.Stop();      
  MyPopUp.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  timer.Start();
}
```

With the following markup:

```
  <Button MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
    <Popup x:Name="MyPopUp">          
      <Grid Width="100" Height="20" Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
      </Grid>
    </Popup>        
  </Button>
```